# Online solution to combine/compound paths of SVG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, path, pathfinder

I have the Google G logo below in SVG format and need to merge the paths to a single path.

Is there any solution out there to solve this (preferably online) that doesn't require installation of new software on my computer?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
   <defs>
      <path id="a" d="M44.5 20H24v8.5h11.8C34.7 33.9 30.1 37 24 37c-7.2 0-13-5.8-13-13s5.8-13 13-13c3.1 0 5.9 1.1 8.1 2.9l6.4-6.4C34.6 4.1 29.6 2 24 2 11.8 2 2 11.8 2 24s9.8 22 22 22c11 0 21-8 21-22 0-1.3-.2-2.7-.5-4z"/>
   </defs>
   <clipPath id="b">
      <use xlink:href="#a" overflow="visible"/>
   </clipPath>
   <path clip-path="url(#b)" fill="#FBBC05" d="M0 37V11l17 13z"/>
   <path clip-path="url(#b)" fill="#EA4335" d="M0 11l17 13 7-6.1L48 14V0H0z"/>
   <path clip-path="url(#b)" fill="#34A853" d="M0 37l30-23 7.9 1L48 0v48H0z"/>
   <path clip-path="url(#b)" fill="#4285F4" d="M48 48L17 24l-4-3 35-10z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: There's no way to do this. The SVG has the G character as one path already, the colours are achieved by using clipping paths on clones of the G path.  If you remove these paths, or change the design to a single path, then it can only have one fill.

Answer (score 1):

I try to find one : https://www.ofoct.com/image-converter/svg-optimizer.html

But anyway I would prefer to do it with InkscapePortable for single svg.
Quite simple:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> → open
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> → select all path
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> → combine all the path
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> → save

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately this won't work for the example posted by the OP. Combined paths can only have one fill, but the design has several colours.